# Nginx: 301 redirect without query strings

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I am redirecting `/example.php?var=value` to `/index.htm` like this:

`rewrite /example.php?var=value / permanent;`

However, the browser ins printing the final uri like this:

`domain.com/?var=value`

How can I have a clean uri like this?

`domain.com`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from [nginx rewrite module documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule):

> If in the line of replacement arguments are indicated, then the rest of the request arguments are appended to them. To avoid having them appended, place a question mark as the last character:

```
rewrite  ^/users/(.*)$  /show?user=$1?  last;
```

Comment: Thanks, @AlexD! So in my case how could I redirect `domain.com/example.php?var=anyvalue` to `/index.htm`? I am trying `rewrite /example.php?(.*) /? last;` or `rewrite /example.php?(.*) /? permanent;` but it is not working, it continues redirecting to `/index.htm?var=anyvalue`

Answer (score 2):

Put a question mask at the end of replacement:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        location ~ /example\.php$ {
            if ($args ~ var=value) {
                rewrite ^ /? permanent;
            }
        }
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi.conf;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        error_page 404 /error/404.php;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @quanta! Shouldn't there be any other way to do this without using "if"?

Comment: No need to worry. Only `rewrite` in `if` condition is 100% safe.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way I found is this:

`rewrite ^/example.php /? permanent;`

Thanks for all.